# Do I need to modify links throughout my webpages once I use MOD_REWRITE?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm in process of cleaning my URLs.

Say I have a URL http://www.example.com/index.php?id=12345&name=some-name

I just changed it to look better using mod_rewrite

http://www.example.com/blog/12345/some-name

Now the pain is the page index.php is not loading any images, css files and the anchor links are all broken.

Location of my image is http://www.example.com/images/12345/some-image.jpg

I have used relative paths through out my site.

Now do I need to change links on all my pages ? Can .htaccess do some trick for me ? Please help.

Here is my .htaccess-

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the second line that I added.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|css|htm|html|mp3|wav|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

This basically says if you see this extension in the URL, just pass it straight to the file.

Comment: Thanks! correct me if I'm missing something. My .htaccess looks like this now. But I couldn't achieve what I was looking for. RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|css|htm|html|mp3|wav|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: What is it doing with that change?

Comment: Try flipping the last 2 lines and if that doesn't work I'll do a quick test in my webserver.

Comment: No luck :(. Hope you got my problem. But I'm sure there will be a solution in htaccess.  **More Explanation** :  After I changed the URL structure, the images that were suppose to be loading from the path http://www.example.com/images/12345/some-image.jpg are trying to load from http://www.example.com/blog/12345/some-name/images/12345/some-image.jpg which never existed.

Answer (score 1):

RewriteCond applies to only the next rule and not to all rules below. Your second rule is not looking to avoid directories and files which exist. Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh...!

I just added this little line in my header and it resolved all my problems :)

```
<base href="http://example.com/ />
```

Now I'm like... Why the heck did my mind take so long to think this one :)